# How can i add sparkline to kendo grid after the loading process?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, sparklines

Guys I wanted to know the ways of adding sparkline to grid after the loading,I myself used the change event but the problem is after clicking on the grid ,sparkline appears!

For clarification ,I've added a video regarding my project

http://jsfiddle.net/psot98/AxMHY/3/embedded/result/

[**Video**](http://youtu.be/_a3sd6teXCY)

**event change grid**

```
      change: function (e) {
                $(".sparkline").kendoSparkline({

                    type: "area",

                    series: [{
                        name: "World",
                        data: [15.7, 16.7, 20, 23.5, 26.6, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5, 3.5],

                    }, {
                        name: 'New York',
                        data: [0.7, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5],

                    }],

                });
            }
```

Comment: Is displaying the sparklines *after* loading a requirement? - Also: You didn't state what the supposed behaviour is, only what it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about : http://jsfiddle.net/vojtiik/AxMHY/4/embedded/result/
You can use DataBound event, so once data is loaded and bound - you show your fancy charts. http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-dataBound

```
dataBound : function (e) {
                  $(".sparkline").kendoSparkline({
                      type: "area",
                      series: [{
                          name: "World",
                          data: [15.7, 16.7, 20, 23.5, 26.6, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5, 3.5],

                      }, {
                          name: 'New York',
                          data: [0.7, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 4.1, 8.6, 2.5],
       }],

                  });
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$.fn.kendoSparkline = function(options){
    // if the grid is not prepared just keep waiting 
    if($(this).find('.k-grid-header').length == 0){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(this).lockColumn(count);
        },50);
        return;
    }
    // kendoSparkline logic
}

$('#kendoGrid').kendoGrid({...});
$(".sparkline").kendoSparkline({...});
```

This method will check if the grid is loaded, and will keep waiting util it's loaded.